# Dictionary literal; adding an array

Tags: swift

Take the two following samples: Why can I not add an array to a dictionary literal from an array variable?

This works:

```
class test{

    var myarray: [String?] = []

    var dictionary: [String: AnyObject]{
        get {
            return [
                "object": [
                    "array":["",""],
                ],
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work? "`Contextual type 'AnyObject' cannot be used with dictionary literal."`

```
    class test{

        var myarray: [String?] = []

        var dictionary: [String: AnyObject]{
            get {
                return [
                    "object": [
                        "array":[self.myarray],
                        ],
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `["", ""]` is not the same as `[String?]`. Horrible sample of code to read btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to dictionary literals. In your first case,

```
[ "array":["",""]]
```

can be converted to `AnyObject` because all `String`'s are automatically
bridged to `NSString` if necessary. Then `["",""]` is bridged to
an `NSArray`, and the entire expression to an `NSDictionary`.

It does not work in the second case because the optional type `String?` cannot be converted to `AnyObject`.  If you change the definition to

```
var myarray: [String] = []
```

then it compiles without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Looking around I found the solution:
'as AnyObject'